# Formatted windows partition

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning

I searched for hours what I can do, but I didn't find anything for my specific case.

I'll try to be synthetic: I had a disk with 3 partitions, respectively 2 with linux and the third with windows. I installed arch in the first partition but the new installer, instead of selecting the partition, selected the entire disk.

I don't care about the second partition, I only care about the windows' partition.

Right now I have the entire disk formatted in btrfs and the windows' recovery partition is also corrupted (the infamous 0xc000000e error)

My goal is to recover all the files from the windows' partition, it would be nice to also keep the whole system in place but I can sacrifice it

Notes:

- I have a computer and many clear usb drives so I can create bootable usbs
- On the computer to recover I don't have any functioning os because I stopped the arch installation after seeing it was using the whole disk

I am afraid that reformatting the entire disk to ntfs will cause potentially both useless and harmful overwrites to the disk

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try [TestDisk Livecd](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Livecd) and the other products that these live boots may contain.

Comment: Hi, provided that I'm going to use gparted live (it contains testdisk), should I format the disk back to ntfs or a scan should detect the windows partition?

Comment: Don't. Another format will just destroy the disk some more. Try to recover it as-is.